# Mysql query for group by month

Tags: mysql, group-by, monthcalendar

I am looking to do something like get all rows from table

```
where date >='2012-05-05' and date<='2012-07-20'
```

I want MySQL to return `"group by"` rows mont wise incremented from

```
2012-05-05 to 2012-06-05(incerement 1 month)
2012-06-06 to 2012-07-06(increment 1` month)
and remaining 2012-07-07 to 2012-07-20 (group the remaining 14 days)
```

how can i write my query to achieve the same?

Thank you...

Comment: This way you would be returning rows *month-plus-one-day*-wise, not just *month*-wise.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this solution:

You can `GROUP BY` the number of months elapsed from your parameter minimum (`2012-05-05`) + 1 to the date in each row via the [*TIMESTAMPDIFF()*](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampdiff) function:

```
GROUP BY TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH, '2012-05-05' + INTERVAL 1 DAY, date)
```

The reason why we +1 day to your minimum parameter is because:

- `2012-05-05` to `2012-06-04` is 0 months, but...
- `2012-05-05` to `2012-06-05` is 1 month

^ Because of that, the row(s) on `2012-06-05` would be grouped separately from dates that had 0 months elapsed when we actually want it grouped WITH them.

---

**Edit**: I was fiddling around with this solution not only grouping by the month intervals, but also displaying the ***from*** and ***to*** dates of each interval.

Check it out:

## [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a0ddf/2/0)

Comment: can i display the date range mysql is grouping by using you above technique ?\

Comment: @user1537158 have a look at what I did in the SQLFiddle demo. It looks a bit messy and complicated but it works. Just plug in your minimum and maximum parameters where it says `2012-05-05` and `2012-07-20` respectively. Also, make sure you include the `fromdate` and `todate` columns in the `GROUP BY` as I am doing in the demo.

Comment: @user1537158 My pleasure! I actually just learned about `TIMESTAMPDIFF` when attempting to answer your question. Now I know something I didn't know before, so thanks for asking the question!

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [case expression](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/control-flow-functions.html) and then group by on the result of `case`.

```
SELECT 
  CASE 
    WHEN where date >='2012-05-05' and date<='2012-06-05' THEN 1 
    WHEN where date >='2012-06-06' and date<='2012-07-06' THEN 2 
    ELSE 3 
  END AS period, COUNT(*)
FROM your_table
GROUP BY period
```

Comment: But buddy the date range is dynamically choosen , not static , just for example sake i had mentioned them the date could be from 2012-01-24 to 2012-12-01

Comment: @user1537158 This is just a example, you should define your range yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this help, I assumed the date range is dynamic like this :

```
2012-01-01 to 2012-02-01
2012-02-02 to 2012-03-02
2012-03-03 to 2012-04-03
2012-04-04 to 2012-05-04
2012-05-05 to 2012-06-05
...
```

So, I can group it using :

```
SELECT *, IF(day(date)>=month(date), month(date), month(date)-1) as PERIOD 
FROM your_tablename 
GROUP BY PERIOD;
```